# Retrieve Column Based On Data Step Variable

Tags: sas

I'm writing a SAS job.  For this SAS job, I need to do the following --

1. Retrieve the value of the field `ActiveColumn`.  This value will be the name of another column in the table.
2. Set `ActiveValue` equal to the value of the field named by `ActiveColumn`.

Basically, I'm trying to write a version of this where I don't half to write out every column name beforehand --

```
Select(ActiveColumn);
  when ('CITY') ActiveValue = City;
  when ('STATE') ActiveValue = State;
  when ('ZIP') ActiveValue = Zip;
otherwise;
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a vertical transpose.  That would be done something like this, if all fields are character:

```
data want;
set have;
array fields city state zip;
do _t = 1 to dim(fields);
  if lowcase(activeColumn)=vname(fields[_t]) then activeValue=fields[_t];
  *may want an OUTPUT here.;
end;
run;
```

If they are mixed type you would need two arrays and loops.  You might not need ActiveColumn if you are intending to just loop over all fields anyway; you can just set ActiveColumn to vname(fields[_t]) in the loop.

If you are intending to have this be more flexible, you can use `array fields _character_;`
which will use all character variables (thus meaning you don't have to explicitly specify them).